# What could be the reprecussions associated with targeting IE7 and using the tag that forces IE8 into IE7 mode on a new web app?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I really don't want to do it, I want to target the latest browser. It seems a little backwards to target a legacy browser and then force IE8 to run in a compatibility mode. I wonder what would happen when IE9 came out?

However JQuery and CSS are both having some issues running properly in IE8, it works fine in IE7 and Firefox and I believe even Chrome. I want this thing to run well in IE7, IE8, and FF at least. Is there a better way or should I just use this tag for IE8?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

What could be the risks for doing this? **I just don't feel right about it but I don't really have any founded evidence to support my fears.** My gut feeling is that it will cause problems down the road and create a potential for much rework. Thoughts?

**UPDATE**: Here is the actual problem itself...

```
if (dir == "back" || dir == "jump") {
     $.get(prevNode.attr("href") + "&bID=" + bID + "&ieRefresh=" + Math.random(), "",
          function(data) {
          p.nav.prevHtml = data;
     });
}
```

The error is:

Object doesn't support this property or method line 390, character 37 (the character that is found by these 'coordinates' is the dollar sign of the $.get()).

Comment: What sections of your jQuery and CSS are broken in IE8? I've personally found it much harder to make IE7 work like FF/IE8.

Comment: Is the prevNode href attribute empty or something? I can't imagine why this wouldn't work properly in IE8 -- I use $.get in my projects and haven't had issues using that and IE8. Have you tried substituting this with .load just in case?

Comment: You never target browsers, you always target standards and test in the most standards compliant browser first to test your markup. That browser is never IE.

Comment: @Rob that's a good point, how can I know if I am achieving true standards compliance?

Comment: Validate your html and css. Once your markup works in a modern browser, and is valid, then double check in other browsers, then look to see how badly IE screws it up. But at least you know your markup isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Look at your code.
- Look at where your doing it wrong.
- Fix your code.
- Watch it work in IE8

Ideally what you want to do is make your entire website compatible with IE8. IE7 by itself is largely incompatible with FF & Chrome standards and requires a lot of hacking.

It's going to be significantly easier for you to upgrade compliance from IE8 to IE9 because IE9 isn't going to deal with IE6/7 code nicely.

jQuery will work properly in IE8. I can't fanthom what CSS works in IE7 & FF (Were talking FF3.6 right? not FF 1.5?) but doesn't work in IE8. This is a clear sign that your set up is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising that jQuery isn't "running properly" in IE8. There are definitely differences in CSS between 7 and 8, but what exactly are you doing in jQuery that isn't working in 8?

Also, is using IE conditional statements not an option? i.e.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
Special instructions for IE 8 here
<![endif]-->
```

UPDATE:

Sometimes using the $ sign can cause problems depending on whatever else you have going on. Does using "jQuery" instead of "$" do anything? I tried out your code in IE8 and didn't get any errors....

Comment: Ideally avoid IE conditionals in favour of feature detection. I can fathom that IE conditionals might be neccesary for IE6 / quirksmode support but IE8 should really behave well enough for feature detection to work.

Comment: True. But depending on the complexity of what he's doing, IE conditionals might help him in the short term while he's figuring out what else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and IE9 both include the IE7 rendering engine (or something very close), it's better to force IE into a mode that you know works than leave anything broken.

Having said that, for best forwards compatibility you should investigate and correct your site to work properly in IE8 or at a minimum IE9.  IE8 is not perfect but if you're not doing any browser detection jQuery and CSS 2.1 should both behave extremely well.  The IE team has a nice blog post about using [feature detection rather than browser sniffing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/14/same-markup-writing-cross-browser-code.aspx) (which is likely the problem here).